# $apply already in progress when sending a click event to a button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-digest

I have a button on my page with an id="viewQuestions" on a page:

```
    <body ng-keydown="key($event);">
```

My code is checking for key hits like this:

```
    $scope.key = function ($event) {
        $scope.$broadcast('key', $event.keyCode)
    }
```

and in the controller:

```
 $scope.$on('key', function (e, key) {
        if (key == 13) {
            if (ts.test.current && ts.test.userTestId) {
                document.getElementById("viewQuestions").click();
            }               
        }
    });
```

When I run the code and click ENTER then I get this error:

```
 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:63:12)
    at beginPhase (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:14735:15)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:14479:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:22945:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:3009:21)
    at http://localhost:2757/app/tests/controllers/TestsController.js:24:62
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:14700:28)
    at Scope.AppController.$scope.key (http://localhost:2757/app/appController.js:30:20)
    at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:12330:18)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:2757/lib/angular/angular.js:22940:17)
```

Can anyone give me advice on this. I just want to simulate the clicking of a button when the ENTER key is pressed. I did try solutions with forms but it does not meet my rather complicated needs.

Comment: Try this, <button class="btn" id="abc" ng-click="functionName()">Example</button> and define that function on the angular scope as $scope . functionName = function() {}

Comment: Sorry but what I want to do is to have the user be able to see the button changed to the clicked state and back. Ashad's solution does this but it does not work when the click of the button is initiated by another event like a keypress.

Answer (score 39):

Your click event is running digest cycle which is conflicting with current digest cycle, `$timeout` would help you in this situation. Wrap click event inside `$timeout` function.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-keydown="key($event);">
    <button id="viewQuestions" type="button" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked; test();"> Test</button>
    Is Button Clicked {{isButtonClicked}}
</body>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.$on('key', function (e, key) {
    if (key == 13) {
        if (ts.test.current && ts.test.userTestId) {
            $timeout(function(){
                angular.element(document.getElementById("viewQuestions")).trigger('click');
            })
        }               
    }
});
```

Whatever you write inside `ng-click` will get called.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umktjpLa/13/)

Comment: I cant since is not my question.

Comment: `$timeout` for zero milliseconds worked like a charm. Thanks!